# Any archive that doesn't use MS-DOS filetimes to avoid 2-second granularity?

Tags: archiving

Are there any archives for which don't store directory times in MS-DOS
format like in zip files so as to preserve seconds during extraction?

What I am trying to accomplish is zipping top level Android folders
from my Samsung Galaxy S8 in a .zip (or whichever archive format) preserving date and exact timestamps. After that, I am trying to extract these .zip files into my Windows 10 or Windows 11 Pro PC while preserving the timestamps after extraction.

I have read an article made by PKZIP that states that the timestamps are in MS-DOS format from 30 years ago. My question is why and is there a workaround if any? Can I edit this somehow in .NET framework or C++ whichever software they used.

I've installed Fedora on a virtual machine in Ubuntu 22.04 and I've
tried to use star archive but the documentation is really complicated
for me due to my beginner programming skills. I'm trying to gather
information from as many sources as I can and learn from that on my
own.

So, I'm trying to see how a ZIP file can extract folders and retain
it's full timestamp.

Comment: You'll run into the issue of the archive being created being stored inside one of the directories you're trying to put in it. Why are you trying to do that anyway? Do you have a practical goal or are you just experimenting? Should I interpret your last paragraph as you just trying to learn how it's possible? What does .NET or C++ have to do with this?

Comment: @gronostaj I'm trying to archive my galaxy s8 and also trying to understand why folders are tricky with timestamps while files aren't. I suggested C++ and .NET because there are posts suggesting that it does preserve all 3 timestamps but it is a little complicated for me. I've even tried to reach out to the developer or auther of DotNetZip but since then nobody reached out to me. 

https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/336

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397957/pack-files-on-windows-and-preserve-folder-timestamps

https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip

Answer (score 0):

> I have read an article made by PKZIP that states that the timestamps are in MS-DOS format from 30 years ago. My question is why

Because PKZIP was originally written for MS-DOS, so its archive format was designed for MS-DOS data formats.

> and is there a workaround if any?

Most modern Zip archivers will use *extra fields* to store the modify time in UTC timezone with 1-second precision. Though it very much depends on whether the Zip archiver on your Galaxy phone supports this extension or not. You can test this by creating a small archive and then using Info-ZIP's `zipinfo -v` to look at a .zip file to check whether it contains the subfield:

```
$ zipinfo -v test.zip
  file last modified on (DOS date/time):          2022 Dec 7 10:08:34
  file last modified on (UT extra field modtime): 2022 Dec 7 10:08:33 local
  file last modified on (UT extra field modtime): 2022 Dec 7 08:08:33 UTC
  [...]
  The central-directory extra field contains:
  - A subfield with ID 0x5455 (universal time) and 5 data bytes.
    The local extra field has UTC/GMT modification/access times.
```

But if you want higher than 1s precision, you would need to modify existing Zip software to add yet another extra subfield for nanoseconds.

(It also depends on whether the Zip *extractor* used on your PC supports this extension – the Zip format support built into Windows Explorer is very out-of-date and you should be using a third-party Zip app instead.)

Other archive formats generally allow higher precision, often microsecond or nanosecond – RAR is one such example. (It still depends on the program whether it stores and extracts times at such precision.)

Comment: Do you know any softwares that utilize zip which stores higher precision than 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Zip certainly is *capable* of storing time with greater precision. In the example below, made using 7-Zip on an NTFS partition, note time: **11.4280575** seconds (though I wouldn't believe digits beyond milliseconds are *accurate*). Whether the software and the filesystem used in Android is capable of that precision is another question.

BTW, there's a "7Z Files Manager" in [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sociosoft.unzip&hl=en&gl=US), though there is no claim that it is [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). (Parenthetically, *7-Zip* works well in wine on *Linux*.)

[image: Zip Time Precision]

Comment: so then is there a way to store files in a old style ZIP while increasing time precision more than 1 second?